# autoload a href="#" with javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I autoload the `#menu` of the first two [jsplayers](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/bar-ui/) so that it opens onload of the page?

Tecnically I need to auto load this

```
   <div class="sm2-button-bd">
     <a href="#menu" class="sm2-inline-button menu">menu</a>
   </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
window.location.hash = 'menu';
```

Comment: You can use this code and when you load the page it sets the path with that hash...

Comment: ok, it loads the code in the url, but I need to open the menu automatically: http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/bar-ui/

Comment: so, when it loads the hash doesn't it go to that location?

Comment: well it goes to the url ...#menu which is actually not opening the menu of the player... don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.querySelector(".sm2-inline-button menu").click();
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() { 
  $(".sm2-inline-button menu").first().click();
});
```

Comment: it needs to work with http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/bar-ui/